# C preprocessor macro and warning suppression for custom variadic-argument function?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions

I am attempting to create a class of functions which can be called with any number and any type of arguments--similar to `printf`, but with one key difference: I would like to cast all arguments to `uint64_t` before passing them to the function. Ideally this should be implicit, i.e. without me having to write `( uint64_t ) arg1 , ( uint64_t ) arg2 ,  ( uint64_t ) arg3 , . . .` every time.

My current solution is based on an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77868721/gcc-clang-enforce-type-on-variadic-argument-list) previous question.

Here is the basic way to do what I want for any non-pointer types:

```
// The variadic function.
void _f ( char c , uint64_t arg_count , uint64_t* args );

// Macro to append two extra arguments comprising the variadic argument list to the function.
#define ARGS(...) \
    sizeof ( ( uint64_t[] ){ __VA_ARGS__ } ) / sizeof ( uint64_t ) \
  , ( uint64_t[] ){ __VA_ARGS__ }

// Macro to call the variadic function.
#define f(c,...) \
    _f ( (c) , ARGS ( __VA_ARGS__ ) )
```

It can be used like this:

```
f ( 'A' , 27 , -30L , '/' );
```

I also wanted to be able to pass pointers to the function, but this trips the compiler warning `-Wint-conversion`, so I had to add some extra macros I got from an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426484/concise-way-to-disable-specific-warning-instances-in-clang) question to suppress the warning each time a function which uses `ARGS` is called:

```
#define PRAGMA(args) \
    _Pragma ( #args )

#define DISABLE_WARNING(warning)   \
    PRAGMA ( GCC diagnostic push ) \
    PRAGMA ( GCC diagnostic ignored #warning )

#define REENABLE_WARNING() \
    PRAGMA ( GCC diagnostic pop )

// New macro to call the variadic function.
#define f(c,...) \
({ \
    DISABLE_WARNING ( -Wint-conversion ) \
    _f ( (c) , ARGS ( __VA_ARGS__ ) ); \
    REENABLE_WARNING () \
})
```

Now the function can also be called like this as well:

```
float f_ = 32.2f;
f ( 'A' , 27 , -30L , '/' , &f_ , &"Hello world" );
```

But, because of the limitation in syntax where the `#pragma` cannot be embedded within an expression, the function cannot return a value. Sure, I could make the function have an extra pointer argument and write a return value to it, but ideally I would want the function itself to return a `uint64_t` directly. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Basically you want to throw away all that is type safety in order to enable an obscure variadic function API... combining two evils at once doesn't make the result good. There's a reason why `stdio.h` is considered the worst programming library ever designed, all categories, all programming languages. So I would strongly recommend to abandon this idea and come up with a more sensible and safe function interface. Like, have the caller provide an array of `uint64_t` and a size.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? The `f(c,...)` macro returns a value just fine when the return type of `_f` is changed to something other than `void`, because the call to `_f` is the last expression statement within the GNU GCC statement expression. You mentioned `#pragma` which cannot be used inside a macro, but you are actually using `_Pragma()` and that can be used inside a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP mentioned a limitation that the preprocessing `#pragma` directive cannot be embedded within an expression. Actually, it *can* be embedded within an expression (spread out over several lines), but it cannot be embedded within a macro definition. However, OP is not using the `#pragma` directive, they are using the `_Pragma( )` operator, and that *can* be embedded within a macro definition.

OP is making use of the GNU GCC "[statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)" extension  (a compound statement contained within parentheses) in the definition of their `f(c,...)` macro:

```
#define f(c,...) \
({ \
    DISABLE_WARNING ( -Wint-conversion ) \
    _f ( (c) , ARGS ( __VA_ARGS__ ) ); \
    REENABLE_WARNING () \
})
```

If the last statement or declaration within a GNU statement expression is an expression statement, the type and value of the GNU statement expression is the type and value of the expression within that expression statement, otherwise the GNU statement expression has no value.

The `DISABLE_WARNING( -Wint-conversion )` and `REENABLE_WARNING()` macro expansions ultimately expand to sequences of `_Pragma( )` operators that are removed after the preprocessing phase, so do not form part of any C expressions, declarations, or statements. Therefore the last statement or declaration within the GNU statement expression is the expression statement that results from the expansion of `_f ( (c) , ARGS ( __VA_ARGS__ ) );`. If `_f` is declared with a return type other than `void`, the type and value of the GNU statement expression will be the type and return value of that call to `_f`.

In conclusion, OP's statement that the expansion of `f(c,...)` cannot return a value from the called function `_f` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using expression statement syntax, which is a compiler extension, use a `do..while(0)` loop instead.

```
#define f(c,...) \
do { \
    DISABLE_WARNING ( -Wint-conversion ) \
    _f ( (c) , ARGS ( __VA_ARGS__ ) ); \
    REENABLE_WARNING () \
} while(0)
```

Comment: This expression yields the return value of `_f` at runtime? Just to clarify, I wish to make `f` return a `uint64_t` instead of being a `void` subroutine. If that is what this code does, that's neat; I did not even know loop constructs could return a value.

Comment: @OhFiveight Loops don't return a value.  Your function has a `void` return type, so the above is equivalent.  An alternative for what you want would be to add another parameter to the macro which would be assigned the return value of `_f`.